# Inherit in Ado.net Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

[image]

I have entity NhanVienQuanLy inherit from entity NhanVien.

```
 var context = new Model1Container();
 var result = context.NhanViens;
 var resultNV = context.NhanVienQuanLys // not exist
```

How to get data of entity set NhanVienQuanLy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this:

```
var resultNV = context.NhanViens.OfType<NhanVienQuanLy>();
```

or when you query in query syntax:

```
from n in context.NhanViens where n is NhanVienQuanLy select n;
```